# ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python

Here's the line that throws this error

```
(x,neighbor) = random.sample(out_edge_list,1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for 1 unique random element. So you're getting back something like `[5]`. If the 5 goes into `x`, what goes into `neighbor`?

Perhaps you meant to ask for 2 elements?

```
(x, neighbor) = random.sample(out_edge_list, 2)
```

Comment: Actually the list contains tuples

Comment: @Bruce: Even if the list contains tuples, you're asking for a list of one element, so you're effectively saying `(x, neighbor) = [(1,2)]`. There's a difference between a list of one element and one element.

Comment: @Bruce: Try using `choice` instead of `sample`. `choice` will return one random element without wrapping it in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution. I changed the line to

```
(x,neighbor) = random.sample(out_edge_list,1)[0]
```

Comment: As Laurence pointed out above, that could be expressed more simply and clearly as `random.choice(out_edge_list)`.